# python sum frames from dictionary value

Tags: python, dictionary, time, sum, append

I have xml file that contains some kind of playlist
and when I parse it I want to sum frames.

XML looks something like this:

```
    <PLAYLIST>
    <type>COMMERCIAL</type>
    <frames>94</frames>
    <starttime>02-02-2021 01:30:55:914</starttime>
  </PLAYLIST>
  <PLAYLIST>
    <type>COMMERCIAL</type>
    <frames>96</frames>
    <starttime>02-02-2021 01:35:55:914</starttime>
  </PLAYLIST>
  <PLAYLIST>
    <type>COMMERCIAL</type>
    <frames>120</frames>
    <starttime>02-02-2021 02:30:55:914</starttime>
  </PLAYLIST>
  <PLAYLIST>
    <type>COMMERCIAL</type>
    <frames>180</frames>
    <starttime>02-02-2021 02:40:55:914</starttime>
  </PLAYLIST>
```

and I want to add to the dictionary and calculate frames in a specific hour so I have sliced date, min, sec... and leave only the hour, but in that case, I can't add multiple values to a key, because the last value overwrites all before.
So I don't know how to sum all frames to that key.

the result should be

{'01':'190','02':'300'}

```
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from timecode import Timecode


file = '/home/Myxml.xml'
dom = ET.parse(file)

lista = dom.findall('PLAYLIST')


listXML = []
for l in lista:

    type_md = l.find('type')  # COMMERCIAL
    start_time = l.find('starttime')  # početak emitiranja
    frames = l.find('frames')  # TC Duration

    if type_md.text == 'COMMERCIAL':
        listXML.append(start_time.text[11:-10])
        listXML.append(frames.text)

listXML = list(zip(listXML[::2], listXML[1::2]))

clock_dict = {}
for x in listXML:
    x_dict = list(zip(x[::2], x[1::2]))
    clock_dict.update(x_dict)

print(clock_dict)


# print(clock_dict)
```

Comment: You're going to have to give more info and make this reproducible to get a good answer (nobody can copy this into their editor and run it). What is library are you using for `dom.findall()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea: also including a google collab link: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1-adWbqegysVqUE32m_IuxAKEZyk_pXZb#scrollTo=6RCpr5fkfHBh

The idea is to use a default dictionary, which allows you to flexibly group by some key and increment its value whenever the key occurs.

```py
    from datetime import datetime 
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from collections import defaultdict
    
    data = """<starttime>02-02-2021 01:30:52:154</starttime><frames>94</frames>
    <starttime>02-02-2021 01:50:52:124</starttime><frames>96</frames>
    <starttime>02-02-2021 02:50:52:124</starttime><frames>120</frames>
    <starttime>02-02-2021 02:50:52:124</starttime><frames>180</frames>"""
    
    
    hour_sums = defaultdict(int)
    
    rows = data.split('\n')
    
    for row in rows:
      soup = BeautifulSoup(row, 'html.parser')
      time = soup.find('starttime').get_text()
      hour_piece = time.split(' ')[1].split(':')[0]
      frames = int(soup.find('frames').get_text())
      hour_sums[hour_piece] += frames


Then the output is:

defaultdict(int, {'01': 190, '02': 300})
```

Comment: Great, I am new to python and didn't know about defaultdict, I learned something new.

Comment: Excellent - glad to help - check out the collections module, lots of handy utilities.